# Set type to Email Address

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm beginning to work with EF 5 & Lightswitch in VS2012.

I'm modeling a database in EF 5 then creating the database and adding the new data-source to Lightswitch.  I have a contact table that has an Email field which is type string in EF, and I know I can set the type for validation to Email Address in Lightswitch, but it doesn't seem to want to let me.  Here's a picture of it:

[image]

What can I do to set the type to Email Address?

Comment: I deleted my answer from the board. I'm not sure why, but it seems something may be wrong with your VS install. My Visual Studio 2012 seems to be populating the different Data Validation Types just fine with everything from 'Binary' to 'Web Address'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of "business types" (like *Email Address*, *Image* etc), is due to the extension that contains these types not being selected for the project. This extension is ticked by default, but sometimes people untick it, not knowing what it's for.

To fix this for your project:

1. Right-click your LightSwitch project in Solution Explorer
2. Select Properties
3. Click on the *Extensions* tab
4. Make sure that the extension called *Microsoft LightSwitch Extensions* is ticked

You can help to insure that this doesn't happen again with future projects, by ticking *Use In New Projects* as well.

Comment: I ended up having to delete the lightswitch project because of errors and re-create it, but this was it - thank you.